# Regex with bash get specific string from multiline file and store as var

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I had a working script which could store in a var a single string without carriage returns or spaces or tabulations of a multi-line file: the git config file.

But it no longer works as github has changed that file's syntax.

**What the file currently looks like :**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
#commented line
```

**What I'm currently using to extract the desired string :**

```
var3=$(sed 's/^[ \t]*//' .git/config | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed -rn 's/.*https:\/\/(.*?)fetch.*/\1/p')
echo "this is repo" 
echo $var3
```

**What I want it to return :**

```
"this is repo"
"git@github.com:user/repo.git"
```

**What I get :**

```
"this is repo"
""
```

Comment: So far as I can see the data does not contain `https`, so it won't find anything.  *code isn't usable so far as I can tell with bash.*  :this regex is not `bash`  it is `sed`, so the shell should make little or no difference (`bash` does support regular expressions, but you are not using them here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
echo -e "\"this is repo\"\n\"$(sed -n "s/.*url = \(.*\)/\1/p" inputfile.txt)\""
```

output:

```
"this is repo"
"git@github.com:user/repo.git"
```

sed's command : `sed -n s/.*url = \(.*\)/\1/p` will print lines that start with anything (`.*`) followed by `url =` followed by an URL. Matching lines will get replaced by the URL, which will get printed (by sed's `p` command).